# Report back to EC2 that UserData Script Failed

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2

If my UserData Powershell script for an EC2 instance fails how do I report back to EC2 that the machine was not provisioned correct and should be rebuilt?

The EC2 instance is part of an AutoScale Group, and I have found this [Set-ASInstanceHealth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Set-ASInstanceHealth.html) command but I've found nothing in the documentation to tell me if it's correct to set this within the UserData?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with the AWS Support it seems to call `Set-ASInstanceHealth` at this point is completely valid. Below is a snippet of PowerShell code explaining the usage in case it's useful to anyone else.

```
function Get-CurrentEC2InstanceId() {
    return Invoke-RestMethod http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id
}

Try {
    # Not do something stupid
}
Catch {
    $instanceId = Get-CurrentEC2InstanceId
    Set-ASInstanceHealth -InstanceId $instanceId -HealthStatus "Unhealthy"
}
```